# itextsharp "the document has no pages" error when i have anchor tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am converting some html to pdf. It is working fine but when i have anchor tag in my html i get error the document has no pages

My code is

```
 byte[] data;
 using (var sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString()))
 {
    var st = new StyleSheet();

    GetStyleSheetForUnicodeCharacters(st);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       using (var pdfDoc = new Document())
       {                            
           using (var w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms))
           {
              pdfDoc.Open();
              var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, st);
              foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
              {
                 pdfDoc.Add(htmlElement as IElement);
              }
              pdfDoc.Close();
              data = ms.ToArray();
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `HTMLWorker` has been discontinued. You should switch to using XML Worker. `HTMLWorker` fails on some HTML streams and this results in 0 entries in `parsedHtmlElements`. That leads to the "Document has no pages" error. This is a "Won't fix" situation. You need to upgrade to XML Worker.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be invalid html.  One way to check is to run your html source through a validator such [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

have you already tried to add a Page with:

```
pdfDoc.NewPage();
```

I think your Code should look like this:

```
byte[] data;
using (var sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString()))
{
    var st = new StyleSheet();

    GetStyleSheetForUnicodeCharacters(st);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var pdfDoc = new Document())
        {                            
            using (var w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms))
            {
               pdfDoc.Open();
               pdfDoc.NewPage(); // add Page here
               var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, st);
               foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
               {
                  pdfDoc.Add(htmlElement as IElement);
               }
               pdfDoc.Close();
               data = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also add a blank Page by using:

```
    pdfDoc.newPage();
    w.setPageEmpty(false);
```

MfG chris

Comment: I just find pdfDoc.NewPage(); which i have applied but no result.
Also after further investigation i found the problem is occuring when i have img tag in my html. if i commented out that it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Need to check that any html tags are mismatched. Example /td>, this types of mistake raised above error.